# How to activate an animation queue

Tags: jquery

I would like to sequence a list of animations using jQuery. The following is my code but there seems to be a syntax error.

```
$(document).ready(function()
  {
   $('p:first').animate({height: 'hide'}, 'easeOutCirc');
   $('p:first').animate({height: 'show'}, 1000, 'easeOutElastic');
  },
  {
   $('#Op-Excellence').animate({height: 'hide'}, 500, 'easeOutCirc');
   $('#Op-Excellence').animate({height: 'show'}, 2000, 'easeOutBounce');
  },
  {
   $('#Lenti').animate({height: '+=300px'}, 'easeInSine');
   $('#Lenti').animate({height: '-=300px'}, 2500, 'easeOutSine');
  },
  {
   $('#Higgs').animate({paddingRight: '+=300px'}, 'easeInSine');
   $('#Higgs').animate({paddingRight: '-=300px'}, 3500, 'easeOutSine');
   $('#Ferrari').animate({height: '+=150px'}, 'easeInSine');
   $('#Ferrari').animate({height: '-=150px'}, 3000, 'easeOutSine');
   $('#Tatia').animate({paddingLeft: '+=300px'}, 'easeInSine');
   $('#Tatia').animate({paddingLeft: '-=300px'}, 2500, 'easeOutSine');
   $('#Charrey').animate({paddingBottom: '+=300px'}, 'easeInSine');
   $('#Charrey').animate({paddingBottom: '-=300px'}, 2500, 'easeOutSine');
   $('#Zur').animate({width: '-=50%'}, 'easeInSine');
   $('#Zur').animate({width: '+=50%'}, 3000, 'easeOutSine');
   $('#jQueryFiorentini').animate({height: 'hide'}, 500, 'easeInSine');
   $('#jQueryFiorentini').animate({height: 'show'}, 2500, 'easeOutSine');

  queue: true
});
```

Comment: hide / show can't be a `height` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JQuery code with the height being a string isnt the problem, actually you can do this same code:

```
$('#Op-Excellence').animate({height: 'hide'}, 500, 'easeOutCirc');
```

And it will work, what it is wrong is the way you are handling the animations within the ready function, so this will work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('p:first').animate({height: 'hide'}, 'linear');
    $('p:first').animate({height: 'show'}, 1000, 'linear');

    $('#Op-Excellence').animate({height: 'hide'}, 500, 'linear');
    $('#Op-Excellence').animate({height: 'show'}, 2000, 'linear');

    $('#Lenti').animate({height: '+=300px'}, 'linear');
    $('#Lenti').animate({height: '-=300px'}, 2500, 'linear');

    $('#Higgs').animate({paddingRight: '+=300px'}, 'linear');
    $('#Higgs').animate({paddingRight: '-=300px'}, 3500, 'linear');
    $('#Ferrari').animate({height: '+=150px'}, 'linear');
    $('#Ferrari').animate({height: '-=150px'}, 3000, 'linear');
    $('#Tatia').animate({paddingLeft: '+=300px'}, 'linear');
    $('#Tatia').animate({paddingLeft: '-=300px'}, 2500, 'linear');
    $('#Charrey').animate({paddingBottom: '+=300px'}, 'linear');
    $('#Charrey').animate({paddingBottom: '-=300px'}, 2500, 'linear');
    $('#Zur').animate({width: '-=50%'}, 'linear');
    $('#Zur').animate({width: '+=50%'}, 3000, 'linear');
    $('#jQueryFiorentini').animate({height: 'hide'}, 500, 'linear');
    $('#jQueryFiorentini').animate({height: 'show'}, 2500, 'linear');
});
```

Now, what I think you are looking for is how to manage all those animations one after another, there are a couple of ways of doing this, one of which is using .promise() (https://api.jquery.com/promise/) so that you can control when the animation finishes, also the .animation() from JQuery can be called many times like this:

```
$( "#Higgs" )
    .animate({
        width: "90%"
}, {
    queue: false,
    duration: 3000
})
    .animate({ fontSize: "24px" }, 1500 )
    .animate({ borderRightWidth: "15px" }, 1500 );
});
```

Another example can be using callback functions:

```
$('#Higgs').animate({paddingRight: '+=300px'}, 'linear', function(){
    alert('This triggers after animation is complete');
});
```

Hope this helps,
Leo.

Comment: Excellent Leo. Thanks alot !